# C# Visual Studio SDK: VCDirectories interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-sdk

I am currently working on a Visual Studio addin in Visual Studio 2015 which will retrieve the global include/library directories relevant to a loaded Visual C++ project.

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcproject.vcdirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2015), the `VCDirectories` interface exists as a member of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProject` namespace.  However, I am having trouble accessing this interface when I have a valid VCProject reference in scope.

```
public List<string> IncludeDirectories()
{
  List<string> includeDirs = new List<string>();

  // assume VCProj() returns a valid VCProject object
  VCProject proj = VCProj();
  VCDirectories dirs = proj.VCDirectories;

  return includeDirs;
}
```

From my understanding of the documentation, I should be able to reference the VCDirectories via `proj` in the snippet above.  But the `VCDirectories` interface does not exist.

The full error reported by Visual Studio is; `'VCProject' does not contain a definition for 'VCDirectories' and no extension method 'VCDirectories' accepting a first argument of type 'VCProject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Cheers

**Edit**

To complete the function above using information provided by Carlos;

```
public List<string> IncludeDirectories()
{
  List<string> includeDirs = new List<string>();

  // assume VCProj() returns a valid VCProject object
  VCProject proj = VCProj();
  VCPlatform pf = proj.ActiveConfiguration.Platform;
  string[] directories = pf.Evalualte(pf.IncludeDirectories).split(';');

  foreach(string dir in directories) {
    if(dir != "") {
      includeDirs.Add(dir);
    }
  }

  return includeDirs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use instead the following properties:

- [VCPlatform.IncludeDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcplatform.includedirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2015)
- [VCPlatform.LibraryDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcplatform.librarydirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2015)
- [VCCLCompilerTool.AdditionalIncludeDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.additionalincludedirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2015)

You can get the VCPlatform as I shown in the approach of this article some years ago:

[HOWTO: Get standard include directories of Visual C++ project from an add-in](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014004.aspx)

You can get the VCCLCompilerTool with the approach of this other article:

[HOWTO: Get additional include directories of Visual C++ project from an add-in](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014005.aspx)

Comment: That's great, thank you.

I found another workaround using `VCProject.ActiveConfiguration.Rules.Item("ConfigurationDirectories")`, from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn655034.aspx) but this seems much more elegant.